# Android React-Native react-native-push-notification:compileDebugJavaWithJavac Failure

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

After some breaking changes by Firebase on 11 may 2021. I am facing this error `react-native-push-notification:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED`.
Below I am sharing following points about dependencies and its versions.

```
react-native-push-notification": "^6.1.1"  
@react-native-firebase/messaging": "7.9.0",  
"@react-native-firebase/app": "8.4.5",  
buildscript {  
ext {  
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"  
    minSdkVersion = 16  
    compileSdkVersion = 29  
    targetSdkVersion = 29  
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"   
    googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just the issue with the **Android Gradle**, since the `FirebaseInstanceId` is deprecated, hence, Android fails while doing the build. For solving this out you can do these, and your app will come back to normal.

- Add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'` to `android/app/build.gradle`. Please note if you already have `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'`, make sure to **comment it**, and add which is mentioned in the answer.
- Add `firebaseMessagingVersion=21.1.0` to `android/gradle.properties`.

After that, clean the Android Project by doing `cd android && ./gradlew clean` on **Mac** or `cd android && gradlew clean` on **Windows** project from `terminal`, and then run the app using `npm run android`.

Comment: Thank you so much you save my time @Alok

Comment: Glad that I was able to do that for you @AjayBatham. Keep learning :)